# How to handle exceptions with Jsoup in java to keep program running

Tags: java, jsoup

my program crash when user inserts a weird url

It should go like

```
while(condition) {
  try {
   String url = reciveURL();
   Document rss = Jsoup.connect( url ).get(); 
 } 
 catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid URL");
 } catch (OthersExceptions e){
    Others.Actions();
 }
}
```

The problem is, this throws "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol", instead of printing "Invalid URL" and the program crash (when user inserts any other kind of text)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Lol, solved myself, but i'll let the question as theres no post on the same issue

You should import  java.net.url, this brings the "URL" type, which triggers the MalformedURLException (Jsoup doesnt do this)

So it goes like this

```
 while(true){
           {
             String url = reciveURL() ;
             URL chk_url = new URL(url);                 
             Document rss = Jsoup.connect( url ).get(); 
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("url mal puesta!");
        }        
   }
```